How to force nginx to see my static files?
I'm trying to output a project to NGINX.
I ask good people to help. I've been suffering for 2 days.
First I ran: python manage.py collectstatic
The static folder has been created!
Here is the path to my manage.py: /home/ubuntu/ubuntu/project/Pet/Django/bewise/src
Here are my static settings in settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')   
STATICFILES_DIRS = []    

Here are my NGINX settings:
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.16.153;

        location /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/ubuntu/project/Pet/Django/bewise/src/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.16.153:8000;
        }
}

And here is my gunicorn configuration:
command = '/home/ubuntu/ubuntu/project/venvs/bewise/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/ubuntu/project/Pet/Django/bewise/src'
bind = '192.168.16.153:8000'
workers = 3

I run gunicorn: gunicorn -c config.py config.wsgi
Everything works fine, but I don't receive static files. When I try to go to 192.168.16.153/static/img/home.png I get
enter image description here
And I don't receive css files either.

Nginx calculates the pathname by concatenating the root value with the path component of the URL. Try: root /home/ubuntu/ubuntu/project/Pet/Django/bewise/src;

@RichardSmith Thanks, but I already tried this method, and unfortunately it didn’t help me at all.
